# why do I get escaping error?

Tags: mysql, perl

I wrote a very simple Perl script that contains the following line.

```
my $q_it = $dbh->prepare('SELECT customdata.Field_ID,
  customdata.Record_ID,
  customdata.StringValue
  FROM customdata
  WHERE customdata.Field_ID='\'10012'\' && (StringValue LIKE '\'1%'\' OR StringValue LIKE   '\'2%'\' OR StringValue LIKE '\'9%'\');
  ');
```

in which customdata is a table.

However, I always got syntax error complaining about the "WHERER" clause:

```
Backslash found where operator expected at /home/wblocaladmin/Robert_2.pl line 18, near "'10012'\"
```

Since it is a quote inside quote statement, so I tried escaping the single quote like one above. Could any body help me spot where I went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: `'foo' \ 'bar'` is not valid Perl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you don't just use double quotes to enclose the string  ?

```
my $q_it = $dbh->prepare("SELECT customdata.Field_ID,
  customdata.Record_ID,
  customdata.StringValue
  FROM customdata
  WHERE customdata.Field_ID='10012' && (StringValue LIKE '1%' OR StringValue LIKE   '2%' OR StringValue LIKE '9%');
  ");
```

Comment: @Kevin, `fetch*` is called on the sth produced by `prepare`, not the dbh

Comment: Yes you have to call it on $q_it not on $dbh

Answer (score 4):

Use [q](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) to quote strings with a single quote in it:

```
my $q_it = $dbh->prepare(q{SELECT customdata.Field_ID,
   customdata.Record_ID,
   customdata.StringValue
   FROM customdata
   WHERE customdata.Field_ID='10012' 
   && (StringValue LIKE '1%' OR StringValue LIKE   '2%' OR StringValue LIKE '9%')
});
```

You can also use heredocs:

```
my $q = <<'QUERY';
    SELECT customdata.Field_ID,
    customdata.Record_ID,
    customdata.StringValue
    FROM customdata
    WHERE customdata.Field_ID='10012' 
    && (StringValue LIKE '1%' OR StringValue LIKE   '2%' OR StringValue LIKE '9%')
QUERY
my $q_it = $dbh->prepare( $q );
```

Note: I removed the semicolon since it doesn't belong in a DBI query.

For the record, the correct way to concatinate in perl is:

```
my $string = 'foo' . 'bar'; ## foobar
```

and the correct way to delimit in perl is:

```
my $string = 'foo \'bar\''; ## foo 'bar'
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to [aleroot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10505594/29995), you could fix your quote escaping. You have unnecessary single quotes around your escaped ones.

```
my $q_it = $dbh->prepare('SELECT customdata.Field_ID,
  customdata.Record_ID,
  customdata.StringValue
  FROM customdata
  WHERE customdata.Field_ID=\'10012\' && (StringValue LIKE \'1%\' OR StringValue LIKE   \'2%\' OR StringValue LIKE \'9%\');
  ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use double quotes to ease your pain but your problem here is that you're just concatenating strings without using the `.` (dot) operator.